# Add a legend in two geom_points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add the legend next to my plot in order to be able to show which color is explaining each variable. How can I do that? Here's my code:

```
scatter = ggplot(vehicles, aes(x = seq(1,108))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = RV),size = 2,color = "blue" ) + 
  geom_point(aes(y= BOP), size = 2, color = "red") + 
scatter
```

I just obtained my plot but without the names in it

Comment: Put `color` inside of `aes`.

Comment: But just aes(y = RV, color = "blue")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be clearer if you can provide the vehicles data as well but I'm guessing this would work:

```
scatter = ggplot(vehicles, aes(x = seq(1,108))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = RV, colour = "RV"),size = 2 ) + 
  geom_point(aes(y= BOP, colour = "BOP"), size = 2) + 
scatter
```